# How to read a file in unsequential order

Tags: java, java-8

file.txt have 10 line

```
Integer[] lineWanted ={2,5,1};
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));

for (int i = 0; i < lineWanted.length; i++) {
        List<String> lineList = br.lines()
                .skip(indexes[i]-1)
                .limit(1)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

            System.out.println(lineList);
}
```

But code is skipping lines and then counting. 
     i.e. O/p getting are for line 2, 7 and 8.

Comment: Calling `lines` multiple times on `BufferedReader` can produce unexpected result. "After execution of the terminal stream operation there are no guarantees that the reader will be at a specific position from which to read the next character or line."

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on doing it this way, look carefully at what `skip` (and `limit`) is doing. You are skipping to the line index you want, but from the current position in the file. I.e., you get to line 2 correctly, then skip 5 lines (actually 4 from `skip` + 1 from `limit`). This puts you at 7, where you get one line to get to 8.

The "correct" way to implement this would be to pre-sort `lineWanted`, keep track of the previous index, and increment by the difference between the current and previous indices. However, as @tsolakp points out, multiple calls to `lines` is effectively an undefined operation: you just shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

The specification of `BufferedReader.lines()` makes it pretty clear that after processing the Stream, the `BufferedReader` is in an undefined state and can not be used afterwards. So unless you have a strong reason to use a `BufferedReader`, it’s recommended to use `Files.lines` to get the stream of lines from a file, which prevents any attempt to reuse the underlying reader in the first place.

You could achieve the goal by repeatedly creating a new stream, but that bears an unacceptable overhead. Keep in mind that even if you skip lines, the file contents have to be processed anyway, to identify the line boundaries, before they can be skipped. And I/O operations are generally expensive compared to computations.

A compromise is to identify the maximum wanted line number first, to avoid processing more lines than necessary (via `limit`) and the minimum wanted line number to avoid unnecessary intermediate storage (via `skip`) for a single Stream operation collecting into a temporary `List`. This may temporarily hold some unwanted lines between the minimum and maximum, but will be more efficient than multiple I/O based Stream operations in most cases:

```
int[] lineWanted = {2, 5, 1};
IntSummaryStatistics iss = Arrays.stream(lineWanted).summaryStatistics();

List<String> lineList;
try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("file.txt"))) {
    lineList = lines
        .limit(iss.getMax()+1).skip(iss.getMin())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
lineList = Arrays.stream(lineWanted)
    .map(i -> i-iss.getMin())
    .mapToObj(lineList::get)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(lineList);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really cannot sort your linesWanted list, the best way would probably be buffering the whole document into String[] of lines, but it all depends on how you want to access the data. Do you want to read only a few lines from one document, or will you be reading the whole document, just in random order?

Answer (score -1):

Just have to move BR inside the loop (No better option able to find, as wanted to do it with BufferedReader).

`Files.readAllLines(path).get(lineNo)`
is another option which give directly the line but not helpful in my case.

Comment: While certainly a solution, I hope you understand why it is a horrible idea to open and read a file from the start for every line you want to extract.